# Eclipse CDT - Shared library dependency issue

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have two C shared library projects in Eclipse, which are called "MyLibA" and "MyLibB":

**TestA.h**

```
int Test1(void);
int Test2(void);
```

**TestA.c**

```
#include "TestA.h"

int Test1(void) { return 1; }
int Test2(void) { return 2; }
```

**TestB.h**

```
int Test(void);
```

**TestB.c**

```
#include "TestB.h"
#include "TestA.h"

int Test(void) { return Test1() + Test2(); }
```

"MyLibA" and "MyLibB" produce "libMyLibA.so" and "libMyLibB.so" respectively.

I also have a C executable project "MyExe":

```
#include "TestB.h"

int main(void)
{
    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

MyExe's properties are set so it knows where to find "TestB.h" and "libMyLibB.so".  Also it links to "MyLibB".

When I compile "MyExe", I get the following errors and warning:

**Errors:**

```
make: *** [MyExe] Error 1    
recipe for target `MyExe' failed
```

**Warning:**

```
libMyLibA.so, needed by libMyLibB.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

They disappear and MyExe builds file if I modify MyExe's properties so that it knows where to find "libMyLibA.so" and link to it but this isn't ideal.

For example, if you were using a .so file that depends on *many* other .so files then you'd have to link to them manually.

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use -rpath option.

In Eclipse CDT, right click on "MyExe" project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> ** C Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Other options

Add

**-rpath "path to libMyLibA.so"**

Answer (score 0):

I have done same in Linux(Not using Eclipse, Manually through Terminal). Works fine.

All .so files should be copied to /usr/lib location. If it is done, by mentioning library name itself, link will be established.

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall A.c 
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname, -o libMyLibA.so   A.o

sudo cp libMyLibA.so /usr/lib

gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall B.c -lMyLibA
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname, -o libMyLibB.so   B.o

sudo cp libMyLibB.so /usr/lib
gcc MyExe.c -lMyLibB -lMyLibA
```

Comment: @rjayavrp-Yes I know it works but say if MyLIbB depends on 20 other .so files then would you have to do -lMyLibC -lMyLibD etc 20 times?  What if MyLibC depends on MyLibX, MyLibY etc?  Isn't there a better way?

Comment: In my sample code above, "MyLibB" already knows where "libMyLibA.so" is and links to it (otherwise "MyLibB" will fail to build).  So having have to specify the same settings in "MyExe" seems very redundant.

Comment: I've tried both "-rpath" and "-rpath-link" but I get either arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized option '-rpath' or arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized option '-rpath-link'